# LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'

Tags: python, django

I am working on a HR app using the small-small-hr set up in django.
Getting this look up error when i run python manage.py runserver or makemigrations. Below is my code for apps.py and settings.py. What could be going wrong here?

apps.py:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class SmallSmallHrConfig(AppConfig):
    """
    Apps config class
    """
    name = 'small_small_hr'
    app_label = 'small_small_hr'
    def ready(self):
        # pylint: disable=unused-import
        import small_small_hr.signals  # noqa
        # set up app settings
        from django.conf import settings
        import small_small_hr.settings as defaults
        for name in dir(defaults):
            if name.isupper() and not hasattr(settings, name):
                setattr(settings, name, getattr(defaults, name))**
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'small_small_hr.apps.SmallSmallHrConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites.models.Site'**
]
```

Comment: add the python & django version with error traceback.

Comment: show your project directory structure

Comment: I am using python 3.7 and django version 2.2. I actually had a number of exceptions the initial one being: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'admin'     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:     raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'admin'.
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)

Comment: @c.grey Project directory structure: C:.
├───.tox
│   ├───.tmp
│   └───log
├───hr
│   └───__pycache__
├───small_small_hr
│   ├───migrations
│   ├───templates
│   │   └───small_small_hr
│   └───__pycache__
├───static
└───tests
    └───fixtures

Comment: @Muhuri.JSON what is your sqllite version

Comment: @c.grey SQLite version 3.30.0

Comment: @Muhuri.JSON refer this --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55512244/no-installed-app-with-label-admin-in-empty-django-2-2-project

Comment: @c.grey that helped thanks

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading to django 2.1 worked apparently django 2.2 isnt compatible with sqlite3